# My Radeon 7570 that comes with my hp envy h8-1409 is not being detected by CGminer (Litecoins)

Tags: client, litecoin, miner-configuration, cgminer, gpu

I'm using Windows 8.1 and CGminer 3.1.0 trying to mine litecoins

What's odd about this computer is that the video card is some kind of HP OEM device, that's getting driver updates (latest August 2013) in the windows device manager and plays video games well, even without Catalyst and/or the SDK installed.  When I do install the latest 13.1 CCC it doesn't do anything, the card isn't even being detected in there.  GPU-z and Afterburner show my card as a 'radeon 7500 series' and 'Radeon 7570' respectively.

[image]

There are all sorts of AMD drivers in the /windows/system32/drivers section

This is what CGMiner says:

[image]

So I go ahead and log in:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I noticed that the new CCC doesn't list 7500 series (not saying they don't support them) but maybe an older version of CCC?

I recently did a driversweep where I ripped all of the 7570 drivers out of the system and reverted it back to a Windows Basic Display Adapter, and installed Catalyst.  That didn't work, I had to do a system restore.

Any suggestions welcome!  Thanks :D

EDIT #1  CGminer would just hang and eventually a windows "This application is not responding" screen would come up before I installed the SDK.  I forgot to mention this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit janky, but I've finally found a solution to this situation.

- Download this driver [sp57510.exe](http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp57501-58000/sp57510.exe)
- Attempt to run the installer - it will eventually get to a point and then fail. When it gets to the point that it tells you 'Unsupported System' with an OK button, don't press OK just yet. Open /appdata/local/temp. In there, find the most recently created folder. It's contents should look like this:

[image: folder contents]

- Go into the /src/ folder, and you should find an ATI Setup.exe. Run that. My driver was up to date, but it did add the AMD APP SDK stuff and now CPU-Z reports that OpenCL is available, and cgminer is chugging away.